# File Reader API not working as expected in Safari, but working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using safari version 8.0.5. While uploading the file, file.onload is working fine.

On continuous process, if i open the file, do some changes and click on upload file button again, the file is not read in safari but works fine with chrome.

The console.log error i see is **File not found.**

hope i defined the problem.

**EDIT-1**

I think i confused with my text

```
readFile = new FileReader();

readFile.onload = function(){
// working fine on first hit. But not working if i do changes in my file using editor.
}

readFile.error = function(){
// this is called after i make changes in my file with notepad. The error says file not found.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does Safari 8 supports `FileReader` and `File` constructors ?

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=File) says it doesnt support `File`

Comment: The issue is if i upload the file, it works. If i alter the content of the file using editor and clicking upload it doesnt work.....

Comment: If its not supported, it shouldnt work on the first instance itself.

Comment: `FileReader` is used to read files, `File`is used to modify them : "Method of manipulating file objects in web applications client-side"

I think that's why is does not work after modifying one of your files.

Comment: I have edited my question. So for not making it clear.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Oh ok, that kind of modifications ! Never tried that, I won't be helpful here, sorry :(

Comment: No problem. Thanks for introducing caniuse.com